# Mobile Light Client Networking

Tags: private-blockchain, network, light-clients, android

I've been able to create a private networking using the command line Geth tools, so I have been trying to recreate it using the Android light client Geth.

On the command line Geth, I made sure the two nodes had the same Genesis file and network ID number. Then I used the enode string of one node to connect the second one to it.

I downloaded the `.aar` package from the geth.ethereum.org site. I've tried multiple versions, such as `1.5.0,`1.5.9`, and`1.6.0`. I imported it into an Android Studio project. There is little to no documentation on the classes, so I had to guess based off other people's questions and looking at the Go source code on the Ethereum Github. I believe I am able to successfully create a Node, and initialize it with the proper networking settings, and supply it with another node's enode string. However, when I check the Android app node's list of peers, it is always empty.

How can I connect the Android light client node to another node? (could be another light client or a command line client on a computer)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The light client use LES protocol. Geth(full node on computer) should add the "--lightserv value" option in the Command Line Options. and then add android client to the peers.

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options